# Polyphasic Sleep and Halacha

Tags: halacha, blessing, zemanim, sleep, shema

I recently read [an article](http://www.stevepavlina.com/blog/2005/10/polyphasic-sleep/) on polyphasic sleep and I'm quite interested in experimenting with it. The article advises the Uberman approach which advocates 20-30 minute naps every four hours, meaning that you sleep about 2-3 hours per 24 hour period. I'm also interested in trying the Dymaxion approach which advocates 30 minute naps every 6 hours. The interesting thing is that eventually, you  reach the point at which you get a full REM cycle every time you take a nap. It seems that from mouths of the people who do this and establish polyphasic sleep patterns, they have more energy and higher alertness.

The first and foremost question is whether one is allowed to do this out of the possibility of self-harm. For this and for the other questions, I'll be consulting my Rav.

Next comes the halachic aspects of berachos and the like. Since I'll only be sleeping 20 to 30 minutes each time, here's where the questions come in.

1. If I'm only sleeping for 20 to 30 minutes, do I wash my hands when I wake?

   - I remember there being something about the minimum length of sleep required in order to wash, and I'm not really sure what that minimum is.
2. When it comes to only sleeping for two or three (depending on sleep schedule) short periods in the night, when should I make my birchos hashachar and birchos hatorah?

   - I'll probably be studying Torah and doing other Torah-related things during the night, possibly before and possibly after chatzos. Let's give an example of this for clarity:
3. Do I just say Krias Shema Al Hamita only the first time I go to bed during the night?

#### Nap Schedule

```
  Nap Start Time | Nap End Time 
-----------------|---------------
| 7:40pm         | 8:00pm       |
| 11:40pm        | 12:00am      |
| 3:40am         | 4:00am       |
| 7:40am         | 8:00am       |
```

#### Zmanim Schedule

```
  Zman Name     | Zman Time     
----------------|----------------
| Nightfall     | 8:00pm        |
| Midnight      | 12:00am       |
| Dawn (Alos)   | 4:00am        |
```

Of course, the contrived example above is overly simplified and isn't necessarily real, but it should help to serve as an example. Can one give an answer on my three questions above given the above example? I'd like to be able to try this, but I need to be clear on what the halacha is so that in my sleeplessness, I don't transgress.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting topic to discuss here and sort through sources about, but if you're considering this practically, I recommend that you discuss the issues presented in this question with your Rabbi as well. This concern is especially relevant here, since it involves applying halacha to an apparently novel situation.

Comment: The gra had such a sleeping schedule

Comment: @simchashatorah Indeed! When I found this, everything made sense to me about how the Vilna Gaon was able to do it.

Comment: @Isaac Moses: of course. This is kind of a big life change and seems complicated from a Halachic point of view, to say the least.

Comment: Two posts on the topic, which might be of interest to you: http://esefer.blogspot.com/2006/03/polyphasic-sleep-and-vilna-gaon.html and http://esefer.blogspot.com/2008/06/segmented-sleep-and-r-simcha-zissel-ziv.html

Comment: This sleep cycle is known to cause health concerns.  I suggest asking a rabbi if the health concerns are small enough for you to experiment with the cycle.  http://www.menshealth.com/spotlight/sleep/8-hours.php      http://www.livescience.com/7449-cheat-sleep-dreams.html

Comment: We know from chazal that there certainly precedents for this type of sleep. David HaMelech used to sleep like a horse according to the gemara in brochos. We know reagrding the yeshiva of shem v'ever that the bochrim used to sleep for a few seconds at their shtenders and then carry on.

Comment: In addition to the concerns about your asking your rabbi because of the health concerns, I would also like to suggest you talk to your doctor first.

Comment: As someone who has a sleep disorder and who has lived sleeping this way for most of my life, I can only say that this can affect your health adversely. It will throw off your thyroid, adrenals, hormones, and damage your heart. I am telling you this from my own experience. I am disabled as a result of it. Talk to a Sleep Medicine doctor, or your own doctor before ruining your health. HaShem does not expect you to abuse your body. You are expected to take care of it. And, even though there may have been people who have done this, you do not know how it affected them, nor do you know how many bec

Comment: nor do you know how many became very ill and disabled as a result. Use common sense. And talk to a medical professional.

Comment: My son tried this for a few months, all enthusiastic about how much more time he would have. Hated it, was exhausted and sleepy roughly 100% of the time. Not for everyone, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You wash your hands before davenings and with a bracha only before the shacharit one (assuming you have gone to the bathroom since davening maariv which seems highly likely)
- You never say Birkot Hatorah as you never really take a break. Ideally you can have someone be motzi you in them after olot hashachar.
- You can say Birkot HaShachar starting from chatzot except Hanotein Lesechvi Vina which should only be said after olot hashachar.
- You will never need to say Kriat Shema al HaMitta.

This is all assuming that you sleeps are under 30 minutes.

If they are more than 30 minutes:

- You will wash your hands each time, but only say a bracha on the one closest to davening shacharit.
- You can say Birkot Hashachar after the last sleep that occurs before olot hashachar.
- You say Hamappil before the first sleep that is after tzeit hakochavim.
- You say Birkot HaTorah after each sleep.

Sources: SA OC 4:15 47:13 92:5 and MB 4:30 47:25 47:23 and BH 4:13 and probably some other stuff that I can't find inside right now :)

Comment: Note that not everyone holds that way about Birkat Hatorah: http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5764/bamidbar.html and http://chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/47/7 (the last paragraph, and also see footnote עז which is even more clearcut) note also that it says that even according to the opinion that Birkat Hatorah is not said again, this is only as long as he has not diverted attention from his learning.

Comment: @Ariel Which of my two points are you arguing against? That if you stay up all night without sleeping you don't say a bracha? I agree there are those that differ (in both directions), but common Ashkenazi practice (in my experience) is to be machmir for both sides and that's why I suggested having someone else be motzi you.

Comment: That you "never say Birkot Hatorah". According to the sources I listed you say it in the morning whether or not you slept. (I am aware there are differences of opinion, but you wrote it as an absolute.) You say "ideally....", but I believe the more common custom is that if you can't find anyone to say it for you then you say it yourself. i.e. 3 opinions: a. Say it in the morning. b. Find someone, but if you can't then say nothing. c. Or find someone, but if you can't then say it yourself. You wrote opinion b, but I believe opinion c is more common. (And you should have mentioned opinion a.)

Comment: @Ariel Don't forget opinion d. Don't bother finding anyone because there's no reason to say it. I challenge you to find a Rishon (who isn't immediately rejected by the source he is quoted in) who explicitly says not like this.

Comment: @Ariel Incidentally, I only claimed to be providing the psak of Mishna Berura/Biur Halacha which I think I did accurately. If there are other opinions (and of course there are) then they are more than welcome in other answers.

Comment: I just wanted to let people know there were other opinions. (We always say CYLOR but I wonder how many people actually do - especially for the better sourced and researched answers.)

Comment: Also, there are those who argue with the last point, and say that Birkot HaTorah shouldn't be said after every sleep.

Comment: @Ypnypn There are? The only Rishon I'm aware of who mentions such an opinion only mentions it as an example of a rejected opinion. Which Rishon are you thinking of?

Answer (score 3):

I am not commenting on Halacha,

however I recal reading that whilst there is a time in which one must sleep before requiring him to wash their hands. I do recal reading that there are poskim who say that if one changes into his pjs. during the day even if he sleeps little he still requires to wash his hands.

Comment: +1. Any idea where you might have read that last point?

Comment: I thought it was halachically speaking but just checked and it is not. I will have a look for you

Comment: msh210 sorry I havent been able to locate it again

Comment: @MosheYitzhak Many people change at least a little for an afternoon nap, especially on Shabbat.  So this would be quite practical.

Comment: @msh210 I believe you wash simply because you touched a part of the body that is normally covered.

Answer (score 1):

I would put this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.
If anyone's still looking into this, I would recommend a healthier way to get more out of your day, sleeping at around 8pm (or about an hour after nightfall so that you will have time for Maariv and other things that need to be done at night) and waking up at 3 am/4 am will give a very decent 7 to 8 hours of sleep.
The reason why this is better than sleeping 8 hours from 11pm until around 6 am, is that this way you'll have some time in the morning without any distractions since everyone's asleep at that time, also since you just woke up, you'll be more fresh and you'll be able to concentrate more. Also, I've heard that from 10 pm to 2 am is the best time to be asleep since it helps you "recover" better.
Also, sleeping less can manytimes make you lethargic and while you may get more hours, you'll lose the quality of the hours, adding up to basically the same amount of productivity you had when you slept more hours, but with health risks.