# Davening schedule for someone with a night shift

Tags: tefilla, time, zemanim, employment

The only way I can really convey what I'm asking here is to tell a [fictitious] story:

Chaim Yankel is a late-hour delivery driver for a company. Since he works before daybreak, his schedule is much different than your average person. Here's how his day goes:

Chaim Yankel wakes up at 5:30 pm, the time in which most are getting off of work. He shows up to work at 9:00 pm, and works from 9:00 pm until 6:00 am. Then he gets home at 7:30, and sleeps until 5:30 pm, where he starts his routine over again.

My question is, how would this Chaim Yankel daven? Would he daven Minchah/Maariv when he first got up, since it would be around that time for normal people, or does he daven Shacharis when he wakes up, even though it's evening time?

Comment: When people stay up all night on Shavuot and sleep till the afternoon, do they say Shacharit when they wake up? Or do they say it in the morning before going to sleep?

Comment: In my experience, Shacharit is prayed in the morning before going to sleep in that case. Do you agree? Do you have any reason to think Chaim Yankel's case should be any different?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10235/5323, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60521/5323

Comment: this seems resolved. But for the anecdote, I have a real similar situation. When I fly to the US for 1-2 days from Europe/Israel, I keep Europe/Israel times to avoid jetlag, meaning I go to bed at 5-6pm US time and wake up before 1am. This means that, in the summer, I pray arvit after waking up, when it is the time in the US, since it is too early to pray before going to bed

Comment: The Shacharit, Mincha and Maariv services are at the normal times with everyone else but there may be differences is specific prayers regarding sleeping. With regards to Birkat Hatorah, that can depend upon whether you follow it is a day-then-night mitzvah or related to sleep.

Answer (score 2):

It doesnt matter when you wake up there are certain times for each tefilla like shachris till chatzos etc so if you wake up at 530 and the proper prayer time is mincha you pray mincha.

Thanks for the amazing question

Comment: Remember to edit in sources for your answers.